# Apple/Google Maps SDK for getting directions data

Tags: cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios, apple-maps

I am trying to build an iOS application that will basically give me distance and route to how to go from my current location to a specified destination.

Does Google Maps SDK or Apple Maps SDK expose such an API to get directions/navigation data without leaving the app?

I know Google Maps API has directions data REST API, however I was looking for more integrated solution that utilizes MapKit directly, if any. Thanks for reading so far.

Comment: For iOS 7+, see [MKDirections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013264).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Apple is not supporting GoogleMaps in MapKit. I used GoogleMaps, and I need to import all libraries and add the functionality by code.

But it supports Apple Maps.